# How to add css in header in magento2

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

I want to include the css for product view page

In **catalog_product_view** layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="XXX_Info::css/optionswatches.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

added optionswatches.css file in view/frontend/web/css/optionswatches.css

after flush cache not include the css in header

If anything i want to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your files are correct position's

**XXX/Info/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="XXX_Info::css/optionswatches.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Your css location will be.

**XXX/Info/view/frontend/web/css/optionswatches.css**

After that clear cache, deploy content, check page source you css loading or not.

Comment: I have checked all above steps ... but not working

Comment: @ManoM also check the spelling mistake too and use incognito mode.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check whether it has been loaded in pub/static folder.
If not you should run below command.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Thanks

Comment: already run it ...but not working

Comment: Can you see it in pub/static folder?

Comment: If you still can't see.Flush Browser cache.
It will work.

Comment: Already removed var, generated and pub/static/ and run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f, cache:flush and also browser cache ...but not working

Comment: Actually It all fine, I have just checked on my setup.
Can you please check path of css.
It should be in 
app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/css/optionswatches.css

Comment: I have checked it ... its all fine

Answer (score 0):

Inside your catalog_product_view.xml,

Add

```
<head>
    <css src="css/optionswatches.css" media="all and (min-width: 1px)"/>
</head>
```

Comment: But i need it only in product view page

Comment: @ManoM I have updated my answer.Please Try